# System.Runtime reference in .Net Core MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, visual-studio-2017

I recently updated my .Net Core (i believe 10 RTM, 1.0.0-preview2-003121?) MVC solution to a VS2017 solution.
After several attempts, using multiple project.json versions and .Net Core package versions, I finally got the application working again in the new environment.
Ofcourse, except for 1 error still poping up when using some objects in my Razor views:
[image: Errors]

As you can see, the error says that I am missing a reference to System.Runtime.
I tried adding this reference to my project in multiple ways, but none worked so far :(.
I tried:
- Using the System.Runtime NuGet package
- Adding the assembly reference in my csproj file
- Adding the assembly reference by browsing to the dll itself on my PC
- Copying the DLL to every bin folder I could find in my solution

Has anyone had this same problem and/or knows a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same problem when upgrading from .NET Core 1.0 to 1.1 and I solved this by adding dependency to [NETStandard.Library 1.6.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/) and updating all other dependencies versions to 1.1.0 instead of 1.0.0 (or some preview versions).

Also you might take a look at upgrade guide here: [Announcing the Fastest ASP.NET Yet, ASP.NET Core 1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/)

Comment: Hi Dawid,
I tried adding the NetStandard.Library package AND updated all Core packages to 1.1.0, but I still get the same errors.
Any other ideas?

Comment: I was also struggling with this for hour or two. Try to remove all dependencies and tools which have "preview" version, one by one and see if this will help.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes VS2017 get stuck with conflicting packages.
A lot of errors seem to be resolved when the project is cleaned and the "obj" folder is deleted.
When you do that, you'll see that nuget packages will be re-attached/re-referenced.
It's kind of a stupid way, but it solved me a lot of problems regarding versioning and nuget packages.

Comment: Cleaning the solution didn't fix it either. There are a couple of prerelease packages still installed, but those should be fine to use right? Microsoft.NET.Sdk, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

Comment: Were you success?  I have added NetStandard.Library, updated packages to 1.1, cleaned bin/obj folders. It didn't help. VS2017 RC

Comment: Converting .net version from 4.6.1 to 4.6.2 helped me !