# Error upgrading from .Net Core 1.0.0 to 1.1.0

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core project which I am getting back to which was working fine.  I ran a NuGet update which upgraded a number of items, mainly going from AspNetCore 1.0.0 to 1.1.0.  The solution compiles fine, but when I run it, I get this exception in the browser:

```
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' 
or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features in project.json does not fix the problem and I can find no reference to it.  Does any one have a suggestion on resolving this?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876898/system-runtime-reference-in-net-core-mvc-application/40886877?noredirect=1#comment68996079_40886877. It might also help with your issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40772884/240564

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem after updating from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 (ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework 4.6.2) x86) using Visual Studio Community 2017 RC.

My solution were to uninstall the Codegeneration design package:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Codegeneration.Design (1.0.0-msbuild1-final)
```

---

**Update!**

The faulty package has since been updated (`1.0.0-msbuild2-final` as of this writing). So instead of removing the package, tick "include prerelease" and update.

[image: NuGet]

Comment: My answer worked at first, but the next day the same error was happening again.  Following your suggestion caused it to work again, but I also had to remove "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"

Comment: @Rono Great! You could try to update Razor and EFC Tools to version 1.1.0-preview4-final. (Remember to tick "Include prerelease" if using NuGet GUI) At least it worked for my app backed by the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

According to this site [Announcing the Fastest ASP.NET Yet, ASP.NET Core 1.1 RTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1/) the .NET Core 1.1 SDK needs to be installed.  I assumed that I had already done that through a Visual Studio notification, but that wasn't the case.  Once I installed it, the site worked.